# No wireless on Dell N5110 with any driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, modules, modprobe

I've tried installing b43, STA, wl, ndiswrapper, none have worked, so now I'm trying brcmsmac

Problem is, I have this problem when trying to **modprobe** ANY module:

```
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.

FATAL: Error inserting brcmsmac (/lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko): Invalid argument
```

Apparently I have bcma and ssb running each time I boot, from lsmod: 
http://pastebin.com/vBwMmuYB

**iwconfig** gives:

```
robawalsh@Dell-Inspiron-N5110:~$ iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

And here is the output of **lspci**: http://pastebin.com/eLHXwYaC

I have run **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**

Under Network Settings, Wireless isn't even an option.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have backports installed. Please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-backports-modules-cw*
sudo apt-get remove --purge ndiswrapper*
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: No luck. backports wasn't installed

Comment: And how about the following commands?